# Hibernate not Closing MySql Connection

Tags: mysql, jpa, cdi

I'm using C3P0 connection pool, hibernate and CDI to EntityManagerProducer
But in MySql ShowProcessList

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9rb2.png)

My Persistence.xml

```
<!-- Nao remover AutoReconect=true -->
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/db_simulados?autoReconnect=true" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="1994" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />

            <!-- validate | update | create | create-drop -->
            <property name="connection.useUnicode" value="true" />
            <property name="connection.characterEncoding" value="uf-8" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

            <!-- C3P0 -->
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="connection.provider_class"
                value="org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider" />

            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="300" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="0" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="100" />
```

In my C3P0 i configure it to max 5 connection.
Why Hibernate not closing connection? with CDI the entityManager is closed normally with @disposes , but in ShowProcessList the connection not close.

My EntityManagerProducer

```
public class JpaUtil {

    private static EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("simuladosPU");

    @Produces
    @RequestScoped
    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return emf.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void close(@Disposes EntityManager manager) {
        // Called Normally.
        System.out.println("Fechou!");
        this.getEntityManager().close();
    }
}
```

How i remove the connections and release to another user?

Comment: Sorry, but it's weird for me to see such dispoal method. Why don't you close the entity manager **which was passed as an argument**? Please do `manager.close()` inside your `public void close(@Disposes EntityManager manager)` method.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry. It's a desired behavior when using any database connection pool (like C3P0).

The whole idea behind connection pooling is to **keep connections open** and reuse them when handling subsequent requests. Because establishing a new connection to the database is a costly operation.